# Using Matlab for Image Steganography: retrieving hidden image

Tags: matlab, steganography

Can anyone help me figure out why my code is only generating half of the Image and cutting off the other half after extracting the hidden image. Half of the image displays and the other half is completely blacked out. Cant seem to figure it out.

```
I2 = imread('c:/df/img/Lena1.png');
output_stream="";
data_size_s="";     %In bytes and as a string  

%We read the size of the target from the stego image (first 16 bits)
k=1;
for i=1:rows(I2)
  for j=1:columns(I2)
    if (k<18) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,1)),8); data_size_s=strcat(data_size_s,s(8)); k++; endif
    if (k<18) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,2)),8); data_size_s=strcat(data_size_s,s(8)); k++; endif
    if (k<18) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,3)),8); data_size_s=strcat(data_size_s,s(8)); k++; endif
 end
end

%We pass the size of the target image from string to integer
target_rows=uint32(bin2dec(substr(data_size_s, 1,8)));   
target_columns=uint32(bin2dec(substr(data_size_s,9,8))); 
data_size_int=target_rows*target_columns;  % Data Size in bytes as integer


%We read the output_stream from the stego image
total_data_size=(8*data_size_int)+17;    % Total length of the output stream (header + target data)

k=1;
for i=1:rows(I2)
  for j=1:columns(I2)
    if (k<=(total_data_size)) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,1)),8); output_stream=strcat(output_stream,s(8)); k++; endif
    if (k<=(total_data_size)) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,2)),8); output_stream=strcat(output_stream,s(8)); k++; endif
    if (k<=(total_data_size)) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,3)),8); output_stream=strcat(output_stream,s(8)); k++; endif
  end
end

I3_rows=uint32(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,1,8)));
I3_columns=uint32(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,9,8)));
k=18;


 I3=uint8(zeros(I3_rows,I3_columns,3));     % We create a empty image with the  dimensions of the target
 total_data_size=(8*data_size_int)+17;
  for i=1:I3_rows
    for j=1:I3_columns
      if (k<=total_data_size) I3(i,j,1)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8))); k=k+8; endif
      if (k<=total_data_size) I3(i,j,2)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8))); k=k+8; endif
      if (k<=total_data_size) I3(i,j,3)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8))); k=k+8;     endif

  end
 end

 %We show the hidden image.
 imshow(I3);
```

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this in Matlab? `k++`; `endif` doesn't seem like Matlab's syntax.

Comment: Apparently he used Octave. To the OP, without the hiding algorithm, files uses and result obtained, we don't even have enough information to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided insufficient information to resolve the problem, so this answer is an educated guess based on past questions from you and similar questions you have posted on other forums.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23118840/1) of yours, **the original edit** had an algorithm which would extract a stream of pixels and then convert them to a grayscale image, based on the target image row and column sizes. Then, you asked how you could extract a color image and I told you that it was composed of 3 color planes, with a grayscale image being composed of only one. So you had to hide and then extract all of them.

I'm also basing my conclusions on [this question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126061-image-steganography-in-matlab-retrieve-hidden-image), posted on Mathworks, which includes the incorrect result. There are two possible explanations for that result, which are effectively one and the same.

### 1st possibility

You have only modified the extraction algorithm to take that extracted stream and convert it to a color image, while the embedded secret is still a grayscale image. A grayscale image has 3 times less the information than a color image. You erroneously tried to put the extracted stream in a color image and 1/3rd of the way you ran out of pixels so the rest was left unmodified (black).

### 2nd possibility

You had actually embedded a color image, one plane after the other. However, in extracting the size of the hidden image, you did `rows * columns * 8`, which gives you the number of bits in the pixels for one plane. Since you forgot to multiple it by 3, you extracted only the first plane. Now you have the same situation as above, where you have extracted one color plane and try to put the pixels in all three planes in the first 3rd of the image.

### Bottom line

Make sure your extraction process is the exact reverse of the embedding process. In the question on Mathworks you said this is for a project and you don't have the hiding algorithm. However, whoever assigned the project should have told you the steps he took to hide the secret. If the hidden image was grayscale, you can't hope to reconstruct a color image. If the hidden image was indeed a color image, you have to extract all color planes and put them together in the proper order. Assuming that in the output stream, you have all of the data of the red plane first, then the data for green and then for blue, the following code snipet will reconstruct your image.

```
I3=uint8(zeros(I3_rows,I3_columns,3));  % Initialise reconstructed image
k=18;                                   % Starting point in the stream, red plane
green=8*data_size_int;                  % Offset for green plane in the stream
blue=2*green;                           % Offset for blue plane in the stream
for i=1:I3_rows
    for j=1:I3_columns
        I3(i,j,1)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8)));
        I3(i,j,2)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k+green,8)));
        I3(i,j,3)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k+blue,8)));
        k=k+8;
    end
end
```

Don't forget the total size of the stream for a color image should be

```
total_data_size=(3*8*data_size_int)+17;
```